# Why are C++ switch statements limited to constant expressions?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I wanted to use macro functions in switch statements before I realized the statements need to be constant. Example (does not compile):

```
#define BAND_FIELD1(B)   (10 * B + 1)
...
#define BAND_FIELD7(B)   (10 * B + 7)

int B = myField % 10;
switch (myField) {
    case BAND_FIELD1(B):
        variable1[B] = 123;
        break;
    case BAND_FIELD7(B):
        variable7[B] = 321;
        break;
    ...
}
```

I rather had to use if .. else:

```
if (myField == BAND_FIELD1(B)
    variable1[B] = 123;
else if (myField == BAND_FIELD7(B)
    variable7[B] = 321;
```

Why are the C++ switch statements limited to constant expressions?

Comment: Since you already identified a viable way of coding your program, why do you want another way?

Comment: Speculation: because they are really just jump tables.

Comment: @FrançoisMoisan: Right, I was silly. But wait: Isn't the condition equivalent to `if (myField % 10 == 1)` etc? So you could switch on `myField % 10`?

Comment: You also should not write macros that way, because it will replace the token `B` with whatever you pass and that totally messes with the order of operations if `B` contains any operations of its own (e.g. `x << 2`). `#define BAND_FIELD1(B) (10 * (B) + 1)` will fix that.

Comment: this was just an example... The original switch had bunch of statements (and used static const defined by macros) and I needed to change some of the cases to handle arrays. So I took them off the switch and handle them dynamically with the if .. else.

Comment: Right, macros can get messy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the strengths of C++ is its static checking. The `switch` statement is a static control flow construct, whose power lies in the ability to check (statically) whether all cases have been considered, and in being able to group cases sensibly (e.g. fall through common parts).

If you want to check conditions dynamically, you can already do so with a variety of techniques (`if` statements, conditional operators, associative arrays, virtual functions, to name a few).

Answer (score 6):

The compiler can generate the fastest possible code for a switch when presented with constants--e.g. jump tables or binary search trees.

When given non-constant values, it can't generate code that's any faster than chained `if`-`else` statements. Which you already have at your disposal anyway!

Answer (score 5):

> Why are the c++ switch statements limited to constant expressions?

Because the check performed by the `switch` statements are *static*. This means that the expressions need to be known at compile time.

In C++11 you can use `constexpr` (if the expressions are derivated by other constant expressions) in your favor. For example consider this function (that replaces your `#define`):

```
inline constexpr int BAND_FIELD1(int B) {
    return 10 * B + 1;
}
```

used in the following simplified version of your code:

```
constexpr int myField = 0;
constexpr int B = myField % 10;

int variable1 = 0;
switch (myField) {
    case BAND_FIELD1(B):
        variable1 = 123;
        break;
    // ...
    default: break;
}
```

As you can see, the above code [will easily compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3577a73df7065533).

Comment: it would not have to be constexpr to compile if it was constructed from a const. Problem is the myField is not a const.

Comment: I guess the OP's question was "why is `switch` static", so I'm not sure if "because `switch` is static" sheds that much new light on the matter...

Comment: @KerrekSB, actually the question asked "why is the switch statement limited to constant expressions". The concept of *constant* and *static* are very different.

Comment: @Jana, [Yes, it would have](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf7b16262a943a10).

Answer (score 4):

My answer would be that the C++ switch is a leftover from the C switch, which is a leftover from antique languages like PL/M.

This case uniqueness is just a chance byproduct of a construct that dates back from the 70's, in my opinion.
It does not guarantee in any way that all cases have been covered, especially given the weak typing of C++ enums.

Considering the piles of assembly code C++ routinely generates behind the scene, arguing that C++ switch is limited to constants for performance reasons seems a bit rich to me.

Many other languages support variables and/or non-numeric expressions in switch statements, and I haven't seen many programmers complain about the possible duplicate case values.

Comment: This answer is the most realistic. Historical artifact is really the most honest answer.

Answer (score 0):

To help answer the question, consider the following (IF it was legal):

```
int a=15;
int b=16;
int c=15;
int value = a;

switch (value)
{
case a:
    // Value is A
    break;

case b:
    // value is B
    break;

case c:
    // value is C
    break;

default:
    // value is unknown
}
```

We would never execute the code for C, because A would be executed instead. The purpose of switch is that check a value which has unique, testable values. Its a clean if..else if..else..if..else.

Comment: the point is that switch is not equivalent to if else if else since it requires static const values.

Comment: Yes, because it needs to guarentee case uniqueness which would not be possible using variables. My if else if else statement was incorrect stated; if else if else still with unique static values. Thx for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Compilers analyze the constant values at compile time to generate optimized lookup tables and decision trees to select a case quickly.
For example, if a table can’t be used, the compiler may generate efficient trinary decision trees using sets of 3 cpu instructions: compare to a value to set cpu flags, branch lower to other cases, branch higher to other cases, or fall through to the equal case.
Remember that C/C++ is concerned with performance.
Maybe a new syntax will be added or compilers will be expanded in the future, but standards advancements try to be incremental and not break code that was already written, or invalidate existing compilers.